# pip is unable to install selenium package

Tags: selenium, pip, installation

I am getting the below error while trying to install selenium package for Python.

> Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionRefused Error(10061, 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it', None, 10061, None))': /simple/selenium/

The command I am using is `pip.exe install selenium`.

Answer (score 0):

I am now able to resolve the proxy/protocol issue by using below command
python.exe -m pip install selenium --proxy="proxy:port"

But with Python 3.5.1 I am still unable to install selenium package and now the error is:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for selenium